# Python: Word Guessing Game - trouble with WHILE Loop

Tags: python, random

```
import random
import time

word_list = ['snack','snore','place']

guess = ''
word = ''

while True:
    guess = input("Guess a word: ")
    word = random.choice(word_list)

    if guess == word: 
        time.sleep(.9)
        print (f"Congrats, you won! the word was {word}")
        time.sleep(.5)
        print() 

        play = (input("If you want to play again, hit ENTER otherwise type n: ")) 
        if play != '':
            break
        else:
            print("Let's play again")
```

I am working on a 'word' guessing game. User has to guess one of the three words to win. I want the loop to continue for as long as the user wants to play. But it seems that once they play once, the random word choice isn't working. Here is an example of my output:

```
Guess a word: snack
Guess a word: snore
Guess a word: place
Guess a word: snack
Guess a word: place
Congrats, you won! the word was place
```

You can see that the word was place, but I had already guessed that word, it wasn't until I guessed it again that it worked.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. I am brand new at Python and just trying to figure out the foundation of this software to the best of my ability.

Comment: Your word keeps changing.

Comment: Because every time you guess, you choose a new random word.  When you guessed "place" the first time, the chosen word was something else.  You should choose your random word OUTSIDE the loop, and only choose another one after they guess it.

Answer (score 3):

Your word keeps changing. Move

```
word = random.choice(word_list)
```

outside the loop (just above).

If the user wants to continue playing, you will need to draw another random word. So in the `else` clause, also put

```
word = random.choice(word_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Seems so obvious now. But learned something new for me!! Thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure! Glad we can help!